# Convert a non-standard character to standard version

Tags: php, character-encoding, ascii, special-characters

I need to change non-standard characters like `’` into standard ones like `'`. How can I do that in PHP?  Right now I just need to change the apostrophe, but it would be nice to know how to change others like the double quote and such.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "non-standard" character.  Why do you want to do that?

Comment: You should probably first determine which character encoding you need (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, etc.), and then determine which you should be serving to the client.

Comment: @Jared This is not an *encoding* problem for once. :)

Comment: @Jared A character substitution problem, regardless of encoding.

Comment: @deceze - I've faced the same problem (due to Word-sourced content). I've (manually) replaced it in the past, but using a `UTF-8` encoding also appeared to solve the problem more simply than modification.

Comment: @Jared You'd have to provide more detail on that fix. `’` and `'` are simply two different characters, which can both be encoded in several different encodings. It's not much different than wanting to replace every "A" with "V".

Comment: @deceze they are? i thought they were both an apostrophe.

Comment: @deceze - In Word sourced content, a `’` is the same as an apostrophe, ie, `I didn’t like that.` Depending on the source material, you can surmise it. Likewise, I didn't suggest to turn it into another character altogether (without supervision). Just modify a page's encoding.

Comment: (Replying to removed comment from OP): `’` is a RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, `'` is an APOSTROPHE (as defined in Unicode terms). Just look at them, they're obviously different characters! :)

Comment: @Jared That's Word's fault for (ab)using the wrong character. Just changing the encoding should not change the character, but maybe Word substitutes the character if you save if in a different encoding? Or *where exactly* are you changing the encoding?

Comment: @deceze wow, okay. I just thought it was another "look" or "style" for an apostrophe.

Comment: @deceze - Hence, this is what we have to deal with. I've found that when I change the encoding of the view page to `UTF-8`, when I copy and paste content from Word, it *displays correctly in a browser*. I'm not a content encoding wizard. It's just what I've encountered. The human factor can see that and see it as an apostrophe, which is the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$replace = array('’' => '\''); //You can add more characters here

echo str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), 'can’t');
```

However, `’` and `'` are two different characters and I would wonder why you would want to treat them as the same.

Comment: this ended up being the best answer for my needs.

Answer (score 8):

If you only want ASCII output, you can use `iconv()` and transliterate:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", "Hello’ World"); // gives "Hello' World"
```

Substitute your correct source encoding if it isn't UTF-8.

Comment: Supposing this is what the OP wants, this is the best solution. +1

Comment: How  can i determine my source encoding?

Comment: @LordZardeck: You have to know it. It'll be tied to the information where your source string is coming from. Consult your supervisor or project documentation if in doubt...

Comment: lol, i have no supervisor and what do you mean by project documentation? also, I'm getting my content from a website if that helps

Comment: @LordZardeck: Well, strings don't just come out of thin air. Every text string must in some form come with encoding information, or otherwise it's just a useless bunch of bytes. If the string isn't in a portable, self-describing format, then this information must be documented elsewhere; otherwise you just have to become more familiar with the entire environment you're working in and how to learn string encoding information (e.g. HTTP headers for web traffic).